# How to identify C# program's performance bottlenecks

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, windows-services

We have a windows service developed in C#. We need to identify its performance bottlenecks, such as - which function is taking longer time and how can we improve it.

We tried with -

1. Procdump -  This gives us a dump file of the process  and
2. DebugDiag - We can read dump file in report format by this and
3. Perfmon - Inbuilt windows tool

Can you suggest any better free/paid tool which can help to identify most time taking functions from the service and good if can provide a hint to improve them.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've used Resharper dotTrace and it works well if that helps...

Comment: The title is an interesting question, but unfortunately [asking for tool / software recommendation is off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio has a performance profiler built in. It can be attached to a running process.

You'll find it under Analyze/Performance Profiler and then you use the big button to change target.

It will give you how many times each function was called, how much time was spent on each line of code, and how much time was spent Garbage collecting, amongst many other stats.